# Is it possible to filter unique values from a column and copy the unique values with the appropriate values from a not adjecent column to a new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

my code for the moment is in ActiveSheet sws

```
sws.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
    Unique:=True
```

It works pretty well but unfortunately i figured out that i need to copy more than just the column C. Means i have columns "C" till "J"and i just need to copy the data from column C AND J. The columns in between are not neccessary.

I read something about using **&** in `sws.Range("C:C" & *declared Variable*).Advanced Filter` declared variable means here that i have to specify what else have to be copied. And therefore i would declare

```
declared_variable = Sheets(sws).Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sws).Range("C:C" & last)


Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
Sheets(sws).Range("C:C" & declared_variable).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:B"), Unique:=True
```

**As a conclussion in the right order**

```
Dim dws As Worksheet:
Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))

 declared_variable = Sheets(sws).Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = Sheets(sws).Range("C:C" & last)

Sheets(sws).Range("C:C" & declared_variable).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:B"), Unique:=True
```

But unfortunately it is not working correctly. Any idea? Like always i appreciate it, thanks.

**Update: 19.04.21**
This is how i had done it but unfortunately it tells me that the method range for object worksheet does not work.

```
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet, rng As Range

    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    declared_variable = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, "J:J").End(xlUp).Row
    sws.Range("C:C" & declared_variable).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:B"), _
        Unique:=True
              
    dws.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Set rng = dws.Range("A1:B1", dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: If `sws` is a Worksheet variable as you show here `sws.Range("C:C")`, Then you do not use `Sheets(sws)` as that would only make sense if `sws` was a string or integer variable. Did you try `sws.Cells` instead?

Comment: @braX thanks for your help. I actualized my post how i had done it ...but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdvancedFilter allows you to select which columns you want to copy as well as which rows. If you put the column headers that you want in the range you're copying *from* into the *copy to range*, only those columns will be copied. (If that makes sense).

An example will probably help. Try this. See what happens.

[image: Excel worksheet]

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim criteriaRange As Range
    Dim copyToRange As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set dataRange = .Range("A1:D4")
        Set criteriaRange = .Range("F1:F2")
        Set copyToRange = .Range("H1:I1")
    End With

    dataRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange, copyToRange
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot ...i will try to rewrite my code then and try it out :) and lets see. Do you see any code logic from my update above? Would that approach in general work?